# Prevent Siri and Dictation from sending my contacts to Apple servers

Tags: ios, contacts, siri, privacy, ventura

Is there a settings combination on current Apple operating systems (macOS 13 Ventura, iOS 16.1) that prevents Siri and Dictation from sending my contacts to an Apple server?

Apple's web page *[Siri Suggestions, Search & Privacy](https://www.apple.com/legal/privacy/data/en/siri-suggestions-search/)* currently says

> To stop apps from contributing information to personalize Siri, go to Settings > Siri & Search and tap the app name, then tap to turn off Learn from this App.

The popup *Ask Siri, Dictation & Privacy* *About Siri & Privacy* that appears on buttons like *Ask Siri & Privacy...* or *About Dictation & Privacy...* on macOS 13.0 Ventura says

> When you use Siri and Dictation, your device will send other Siri Data, such as:
>
> - Contact names, nicknames, and relationships (for example, “my dad”), if you set them up in your contacts

These statements are contradictory. As per the web page, switching both *Show Siri Suggestions for contacts* and *Learn from this application* for *Contacts.app* should be enough to prevent Siri and Dictation from accessing my contacts. Yet, per the popup it does send them anyway.

The web page also states that *any information sent to Apple does not identify you, and is associated with a 15-minute random, rotating device-generated identifier*. Unfortunately, that's insufficient if it includes all my contacts. Any hacker, government agency or *Apple and its subsidiaries and agents* who does get access to the full list of people that I know may easily deduct who I am and abuse that information.

Apple reformulates these statements almost every year and claims that *Siri is designed to protect your information and enable you to choose what you share.* Yet this this contradiction remains. [Similar questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58450/how-to-prevent-dictation-from-accessing-sending-your-contacts) have been asked here before, but their answers are speculative or impractical. Does anybody **know** how to configure Siri and Dictation to avoid sending contacts to Apple?